# Python invalid syntax

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am debugging a developers a code and am somewhat new to python. I am stuck on the following line of code

```
 if a >= b + c and \


            not d :


    d = True
```

I receive an invalid syntax error on the first/second line of code. Can you guys please help?

Comment: You shouldn't be debugging his code if you know less than him. Not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if a >= b + c and not d :
    d = True
```

Two things: 1) indentations and linebreaks are important in python. You should check the language syntax. 2) Check the [style guide for python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).